# How does GitHub android app force authentication?

Tags: java, android, github, android-authenticator

I am digging through the [GitHub android app source code](https://github.com/github/android).

I am trying to find out how do they force the `LoginActivity` to show up when the app is first started. 
In their manifest [they seem to have `HomeActivity` as the MAIN](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/AndroidManifest.xml#L39) and [`LoginActivity` is only launched explicitly](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/AndroidManifest.xml#L236).

So that means that always `HomeActivity` is launched when the app first opens up. However, I don't see any logic in [HomeActivity](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/user/HomeActivity.java) that shows that they check whether the account is present or not, if its not present then go to `LoginActivity`

In the code `LoginActivity` is [only launched from here](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/accounts/AccountAuthenticator.java#L74).

Comment: SharedPreferences, if an account is saved log in if not show the activity. I don't know how they do it but it's a way of how it can be done..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, the whole Android account authentication and sync adapters mechanism may be rather complicated at first look, and GitHub Android app adds another layer of complexity there, but I'll try to explain you the whole flow (I hope that my understanding is correct).

At first, I'd recommend you [this article](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) about Android Authenticator if you are not familiar with the subject yet. GitHub Android uses exactly the same mechanism, described in that article.

You are right, `HomeActivity` is launched first. It then launches [OrganizationLoader](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/repo/OrganizationLoader.java?source=c) to load a list of orgs. That loader invokes method from `OrganizationService` which is a part of [GitHub Java API](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core).
GitHub Android uses `RoboGuice` to configure injecting of most commonly used classes like GitHub API services. You can see that OrganizationService is created in [ServicesModule](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ServicesModule.java).
It takes `GithubClient` as a constructor parameter and there is also a [GitHubModule](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/GitHubModule.java) which is configured to return [AccountClient](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/accounts/AccountClient.java) when an instance of `GitHubClient` is needed.
`AccountClient` overrides `configureRequest()` method and invokes

`String token = account.getAuthToken();`

This is a method of [GitHubAccount](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/accounts/GitHubAccount.java?source=c) class, which invokes a method from internal Android's `AccountManager`. And `AccountManager` is configured to use that [AccountAuthenticator](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/accounts/AccountAuthenticator.java#L74) you've talked about, which returns `LoginActivity` intent if there is no account on device.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great! I think link for `this article` is broken. Can you please post the article link? Thanks again for help.

Answer (score 2):

The app is using the Android account system, which is actually implemented in the class you already found. That account system will at some point call `getAuthToken()`, and there it's a simple check [whether the password is empty](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/accounts/AccountAuthenticator.java#L160), that returns the Intent for the LoginActivity to the account management system. Using that intent, the account management system will call back into the app and finally invoke the LoginActivity.